# What happened to my git repo after rebase and pull / push?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I've got `master` and `fun` branches in my local and remote git repos. To keep things clean after committing some new fixes to `master`, I decided to try the `rebase` command:

```
git checkout fun
git rebase master
git push
```

Git gave the error: *Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart*, so I did:

```
git pull
git push
```

This required me to merge on pull, yet seemed to work fine. Although git's history started to look confusing with what appears to be duplicated commits. I created a tiny test commit to master:

```
git checkout master
git commit -a
git push
```

Now I have a confusing git history with what seems to be three branches and duplicate commits:

[image: Confusing git history]

1. What did I do wrong that created the duplicate commits?
2. How can I clean up the repo to remove the duplicates and get back to only two branches?
3. How can I keep the history looking simple in the future?

--

Edit:

TL;DR answer: **Don't `rebase` something that's already been `push`ed.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `git rebase` made the copies.  This is in fact how `git rebase` works: it makes copies, because it must, because the new commits differ from the old ones.

In this case probably the *only* difference is that the new copies (which are in fact the pink ones shown lower down) point to commit `abf0c11` as their starting-point, while the old ones (in yellow and higher-up) point to commit `4009ff9` as their starting point.<sup>1</sup>

The merge went easily because the duplicates were duplicates, but now you've embedded both histories into the merged result.  Both of these histories are now also copied to your remote repository.

If you want to get rid of one of these chains, you must also get rid of the merge (commit `603c2f0`), and then force the remote to change *its* `fun` branch-name to point to one of two remaining tip commits (`3316703` or `141cef4`)—whichever one you wish to retain.  Then you can also force *your* git to change *your* `fun` branch-name to point to the same tip commit.

At this point, you and the remote will be in agreement as to which commit `fun` points to (one of these two branch tips).  However, if anyone cloned or fetched from your remote during the period when its `fun` pointed to the merge, *they* will have both copies *and* the merge, and you must also get *them* to do these steps.

There's nothing wrong with doing all this, it's just a pain.  This is why it's generally advised to rebase only *unpublished* history: everyone who has the old history must pick up the new history.  With unpublished history, you're the only one with the old history, so there's no one else who has to do extra work.

---

<sup>1</sup>This glosses over one other big difference, which is that the source tree for each commit in the *new* chain has whatever updates were made to whatever files were changed between `4009ff9` and `abf0c11`.  The source tree for the commits in the old chain do not.

Comment: Would using `git merge` to bring in the changes from `master` have resulted in no duplicates?

Comment: Yes.  You would get the (first of the) original 3 (gold/yellow) commits as one of the two parent commits of the merge, and `abf0c11` as the other parent of that merge.  If you're sure no one else has copies of everything you have so far, and if you have permission to force-push to the `origin` repository, you can make this look however you like.  If not, though, you might as well just retain this somewhat tangled history.